# Queue don't update items in thread python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, queue

I am running python scripts on Raspberry pi 4.

My app uses a phone to signal the raspberry to start an operation.

In my main script, I initiate a TCP class to handle the communication between the phone and the raspberry.

```
def connect_to_phone(self):
        self.session = RaspTCP(self.phone_ip)
        print("Enter the IP of the raspberry pi at the phone app and press start")
        print(id(self.session.data_queue))
        self.session.data_queue.get()
        self.state = States.Record
```

In the TCP class I use Queue and I update it in an recieve thread:

```
class RaspTCP:
    """Create communitcation with phone.
    """
    def __init__(self, phone_IP: str, tx_port: int = 7800, rx_port: int = 7801):
        """Init the class
        """
        self.PC_IP = ni.ifaddresses('wlan0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
        self.Phone_IP = phone_IP
        self.rasp_port = tx_port
        self.phone_port = rx_port
        self.data_queue = queue.Queue()
        print(id(self.data_queue))
        self.init_server()
        start_new_thread(self.receive_thread, ("a",))
```

Receive function that runs as a thread:

```
# thread function
    def receive_thread(self, c):
        while True:
            
            # establish connection with client
            c, addr = self.server.accept()
            
            print('Connected to :', addr[0], ':', addr[1])

            # data received from client
            data = c.recv(1024)
            if len(data) > 0:
                self.data_queue.put(data)
                print(id(self.data_queue))
                print(data)
            if not data:
                break
    
        # connection closed
        c.close()
```

My problem is that the script gets stuck `self.session.data_queue.get()`, probably because it is empty, but when I debug the TCP class I can see new messages from the phone. Also print them without any problem with command `print(data)`.

I am not sure if it relates to the operating system, because it worked before, and now the messages get stuck in the TCP class, even though it is the same queue in the main script.

Comment: Why to you have a double assignment of the queue?

Comment: I did `import queue` so I need to initiate the queue with queue.Queue

Comment: Your comment seems to be unrelated. I was talking about `self.data_queue = self.data_queue = ...`.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I edited the post. It was a typo mistake in the post.